# Fail-safe strategy/best practice for AAR dependency

Tags: android, aar

I am relatively new to Android programming. I have read some books and posts online trying to figure out a fail-safe strategy to handle this AAR dependency issue, but none of them gave me satisfactory answers.

We are trying to develop an AAR and plan to distribute it to 3rd-party Android developers. Our AAR depends on a number of external libs, and the 3rd-party developers' projects might use some of the libs as well. I am not sure how to handle some of the issues that arise from such a transitive dependency scenario.

For example, say our AAR depends on lib A of version 1.0. And a 3rd-party developer's project depends on lib A of version 0.9. So when he starts to use our AAR, it seems that he has to upgrade to 1.0 in order for our AAR to function properly. But what if the 3rd-party dev doesn't have the "luxury" to upgrade at will? Similar issue exists in the other way around, that is,  the 3rd-party developer uses a higher version of lib A than our AAR.

Does such a fail-safe strategy exist to enable our 3rd-party developers to blindly drop our AAR into their projects and everything just works? If not, what's the best practice to build/distribute our AAR, so that minimal disruption is caused on the 3rd-party developers' side?

We use Android Studio/Gradle for our build process.